# How do I return a method paramenter with RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two method signatures at the moment.

```
public ActionResult Edit(bool? failed)

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Update(FormCollection collection)
```

In the Update method when the password update fails I want to return to the Edit action with failed == true. However using the line

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", true);
```

doesn't seem to achieve this. (I do end up at the Edit Action but the bool value is null.) How else can I redirect to an action and still have the bool value hold?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close - try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { failed = true });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid RedirectToAction isn't as simple as that... you need to pass the parameter as a route value dictionary. Try:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { failed = true });
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx